# Cannot get string of input from variable

Tags: javascript

So as said in last question i was making some console shet for my other stuff and got into some problems

i wanted to get string from input to variable to split it but it does not get anything, it's clear :\

this was my variable code

```
var args = consoleInput.value.split(/(\s+)/)
```

and then i wanted to see it using console log like this

```
console.log(args)
```

but output is this

```
>[""]
```

And nothing else

JS:

```
const consoleInput = document.getElementById("input");

var args = consoleInput.value.split(/(\s+)/)
console.log(args)
```

HTML:

```
<div class="inputTextDiv">
   <span id="inputText"></span><br>
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Insert Command ;P" id="input">
```

Comment: You have to reference `inputText.value` to get the contents of the text box.

Comment: `var args = inputText.value.split(/(\s+)/)` 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined at main.js:26`

Comment: That could mean that `inputText` is `null`, meaning that there's no element in the DOM with that id.

Comment: ... at the time of execution

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.  Can you please remove any code that isn't relevant to your question (does the useConsole stuff have anything to do with anything?), include the relevant HTML, and be clearer about what the problem you're having is?

Comment: `<div class="inputTextDiv">
                <span id="inputText"></span><br></div>`

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]. Please do NOT post code in comments

Comment: Is consoleInput a form field?

Comment: Edited and added something you were asking for i think

Comment: You need to add a listener `input.addEventListener("input",fn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the reason you were seeing an empty array is because you were running your code while the input field was empty.

Here I've attached it to fire whenever the input field receives input:

```js
document.querySelector('input').oninput = () => {
  const consoleInput = document.getElementById("input");
  var args = consoleInput.value.split(/(\s+)/)
  console.log(args)
}
```

```html
<div class="inputTextDiv">
   <span id="inputText"></span><br>
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="Insert Command ;P" id="input">
```

(I also suspect that your regex ought to be `/\s+/` instead of `/(\s+)/`, unless you really want to be capturing the spaces as part of the array.)

Comment: You can split empty strings without errors

Comment: Yep, but the capture group in the regex includes the spaces in the array instead of just splitting on them, which I'm guessing wasn't intended.